# Yiddish Woman name - Malya

Tags: history, names, yiddish

In my grandmother's family history in Galicia, I have seen a Yiddish name being used by quite a few women - Malya. My question is what is the Jewish origin of the use of this name and what does it mean? This is related to Judaism as my grandmothers Shem Kodesh was Malya as well and I want to know the origin of such a use of the name.

Comment: Maybe provide a spelling? Sometimes Yiddish name origins are only identifiable by their spelling as the pronunciation usually differs from Hebrew. For example, Tevye is spelled טביה, which we know to be pronounced as Tuvia in Hebrew, meaning Tevye is the Yiddish pronunciation of Tuvia.

Comment: See http://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Malaya

Comment: @DanF - if that link speaks truth, i wouldn't want to name my child mayla

Comment: @EzraHoerster Agreed. That's why I left it as a comment. I am skeptical that it's the correct interpretation. I have not heard of the word "Mal" as a synonym for "mar" which means "bitter". And "Yah" is one of G0-d's names. So the name means "bitter G-d"? I don't think so! Considering that one of Obama's kids is named "Malya", it could be an African name, possibly?

Comment: `This is related to Judaism as my grandmothers Shem Kodesh was Malya` What is a _shem kodesh_? Other than names of God, I am not sure exactly how names can be holy, and am also unsure why this is on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alexander Harkavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Harkavy) writes in his [Yiddish-English-Hebrew Dictionary (1928 edition)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43567&st=&pgnum=576) that מאַלע /male/ (which with a "weak *lamed*" is /malye/) is a backformation from מלכּה /malke/ (which means queen), since מלכּה sounds like a diminutive (the suffix /-ke/ often denotes diminutives).

However, [Max Weinreich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Weinreich) cites [Dov Sadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dov_Sadan) as suggesting that מאַליע /malye/ = מאַכליע /makhlye/, which both come from the Biblical [מחלה /makhla/](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27?lang=bi), and that the derivation from מלכּה is a *drash* (see [here, note 10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43646&st=&pgnum=121)).

The context of Sadan's suggestion is Weinreich's [article](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43646&st=&pgnum=102) on the dialectical pronunciation in some Hebrew/Yiddish speaking communities in Europe, whereby the letter ח /kh/ gets pronounced like a ה /h/ (when starting a syllable) or not at all (when syllable-final) -- see the article for more details.  Sadan suggests that the name pronounced Malye comes from Ma(kh)lye, where the /kh/ sound got dropped.  In a similar vein, he suggests that the second component in the name אָשר־לעמל /osher-leml/ (which ostensibly means Asher Little-Lamb) comes from לחמו /lakhmo/, from [Jacob's blessing to Asher](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.20?lang=bi).